# ORA-25408 in python module oracledb

Tags: python, oracle

I have a Python3 application running in a Docker container.
The application through the Oracle thick client (Client Shared Library 64-bit - 21.13.0.0.0) connects to the Oracle database (19.0.0) via TNS.
TNS example:

```
DB =
    (description=
       (address = (host = 10.1.1.2)(protocol = tcp)(port = 1521))
       (address = (host = 10.1.1.3)(protocol = tcp)(port = 1521))
     (failover = yes)
     (connect_data =  
       (service_name = DB)
       (failover_mode = 
         (type = select)
          (method = basic)
       )
  )
)
```

The problem is that periodically a message appears in the application logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/app/mtu_service.py", line 45, in tracking_history
    change_read_status(recipient_id, mailing_id)
  File "/app/db_service.py", line 89, in change_read_status
    cursor.execute(sql, [first_id, second_id])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oracledb/cursor.py", line 383, in execute
    impl.execute(self)
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/cursor.pyx", line 243, in oracledb.thick_impl.ThickCursorImpl.execute
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 431, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_odpi
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 421, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_info
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-25408: can not safely replay call
```

What could be causing the error?

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/ora-25408-can-not-safely-replay-call-7684

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already seen this article before. I'm sure the last switchover was over a year ago. Failover more than two years ago.